# How to send JSON using JSF2 Primefaces Request Context to Highchart?

Tags: json, jsf-2, primefaces, highcharts

Hi I've been strugling with this for hours, I want to send my POJO in JSON format using Primefaces Request Context to a Highchart inside my JSF to update its value.
Basically I am following this solution of @Bhesh Gurung from his own stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032877/how-to-send-a-pojo-as-a-callback-param-using-primefaces-requestcontext)
but I cant seem to make it work.  Right now it is throwing a:

> Cannot find component with identifier "pieData" referenced from "j_idt31".

I want to sucessfully create a highchart using the JSON data through the Primefaces Request Context.  Please help Thanks in advance.

This are my codes below

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped

public class PieDataProvider {

        public void retrievePieData() { 
            List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
            categories.add("Electronic");
            categories.add("Food");
            categories.add("Liguor");
            categories.add("Stationary");
            categories.add("Mechanical");

            List<Integer> itemCounts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            itemCounts.add(5);
            itemCounts.add(20);
            itemCounts.add(1);
            itemCounts.add(50);
            itemCounts.add(10);

            RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            reqCtx.addCallbackParam("categories", new Gson().toJson(categories));
            reqCtx.addCallbackParam("itemCounts", new Gson().toJson(itemCounts));
            System.out.println(categories);
        }

 }
```

My xhtml page5.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<ui:composition template="/template/common/commonLayout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:head>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"
                src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"
                src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"
            </script>


            <script type="text/javascript">
                function feedPieData(xhr, status, args) {
                    var categories = eval('(' + args.categories + ')');
                    var itemCounts = eval('(' + args.itemCounts + ')');

                    options.xAxis.categories = categories;

                    var series = {
                        data : []
                    };

                    series.name = new Date().toString();
                    series.data = itemCounts;

                    options.series = [ series ];

                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                }
            </script>

        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <p:commandLink action="#{pieDataProvider.retrievePieData}"
                oncomplete="feedPieData(xhr, status, args);" value="Pie chart demo"
                update="pieData" />
        </h:body>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="footer">
        <h2>This is page5 Footer</h2>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

**UPDATE: MODIFIED XHTML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/template/common/commonLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:head>
                <script type="text/javascript"
                    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() {
                        $('#container')
                                .highcharts(
                                        {
                                            chart : {
                                                plotBackgroundColor : null,
                                                plotBorderWidth : null,
                                                plotShadow : false
                                            },
                                            title : {
                                                text : 'Most used words, 2010'
                                            },
                                            tooltip : {
                                                pointFormat : '{series.name}: {point.percentage}',
                                                percentageDecimals : 1
                                            },
                                            plotOptions : {
                                                pie : {
                                                    allowPointSelect : true,
                                                    cursor : 'pointer',
                                                    dataLabels : {
                                                        enabled : true,
                                                        color : '#000000',
                                                        connectorColor : '#000000',
                                                        formatter : function() {
                                                            return '<b>'
                                                                    + this.point.name
                                                                    + '</b>: '
                                                                    + this.percentage
                                                            //+ ' %'
                                                            ;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            series : [ {
                                                type : 'pie',
                                                name : 'Browser share',
                                                data : [ [ 'Red', 45.0 ],
                                                        [ 'Orange', 26.8 ], {
                                                            name : 'Yellow',
                                                            y : 12.8,
                                                            sliced : true,
                                                            selected : true
                                                        }, [ 'Green', 8.5 ],
                                                        [ 'Blue', 6.2 ],
                                                        [ 'Violet', 0.7 ] ]
                                            } ]
                                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function feedPieData(xhr, status, args) {
                        var categories = JSON.parse(args.categories);
                        var itemCounts = JSON.parse(args.itemCounts);

                        var series = {
                            data : []
                        };
                        options.series[0].data.length = 0;
                        series.data = categories;
                        series.data = itemCounts;

                        options.series = [ series ];

                        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                    }
                </script>

                <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
                <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
            </h:head>
            <h:body>

                <div id="container"
                    style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                <h:form>
                    <p:commandLink action="#{pieDataProvider.retrievePieData}"
                        oncomplete="feedPieData(xhr, status, args);"
                        value="Pie chart demo" />
                </h:form>
            </h:body>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="footer">
            <h2>This is page5 Footer</h2>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've got several questions. 1. Where do you have JSF/PF component with id `pieData` in your view? 2. Where is the enclosing `<h:form>`?

Comment: @skunstsel I am trying to recreate this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032877/how-to-send-a-pojo-as-a-callback-param-using-primefaces-requestcontext 
so far I have not figured out where I should put the pieData component in the xhtml and how to initialize/render the highchart from the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to fail to understand that Highcharts is a JavasScript environment that *runs solely on the client*, while PrimeFaces/JSF is on the server side and they act in this context simply as HTML, CSS and JavaScript code generator.

In your particular case, PrimeFaces is simply used *to send data from the server to the client via `RequestContext`*. After AJAX call completes and effectively, serialized data is received by the client, you call a JavaScript function *that creates a Highcharts JS component entirely on the client from the received data*.

All in all, it yields us with the following setup.

** The view elements **

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandLink action="#{pieDataProvider.retrievePieData}"
                   oncomplete="feedPieData(xhr, status, args);"
                   value="Generate pie chart" />
</h:form>
```

** The JavaScript **

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function feedPieData(xhr, status, args) {
        var categories = JSON.parse(args.categories);//serialized data from server
        var itemCounts = JSON.parse(args.itemCounts);//serialized data from server

        //next you create the chart and show it
    }
</script>
```

** The action method **

```
public void retrievePieData() { 
    List<String> categories = generateCategories();
    List<Integer> itemCounts = generateItems();
    RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    reqCtx.addCallbackParam("categories", new Gson().toJson(categories));//additional serialized data to be sent
    reqCtx.addCallbackParam("itemCounts", new Gson().toJson(itemCounts));//additional serialized data to be sent
}
```

Comment: @skunstel sir I have modified my code and initialized a highchart on page load,
wraped my command button around an h:form tag, but when I press the command button it gives me 
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson

Comment: You need to import [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. For example, with Maven you could do:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Sir Im sure I have properly imported my Gson dependency there is also no errors on my PieDataProvider class.  If you like I could post my code at github I really want to figure this out <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: fixed the Gson error using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961336/i-am-getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-gson-gson-error-even it seems you have to put the gson jar manually inside your project if its a web app

Comment: Making a clean build of your project does that (readding libraries) too. Glad you made it working!

Comment: I still couldn't get to render my Highcharts but I could already pass my objects/JSON through RequestContext.  I think its just a matter of proper formatting of my JSON to render my chart.  Thanks for your patience really helped me sir! :)

Comment: @skuntsel is this useful in case of a datatable ?