# JSF primefaces and d3.json integration error

Tags: json, jsf, primefaces, d3.js

i want to return a JSON from primefaces to d3 with the help of d3.json,but it is throwing error.

My primefaces bean,

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class JsonBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

JsonExample jse=new JsonExample();


public void prepareChartDate() {

    RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    reqCtx.addCallbackParam("chartData",jse.createJson());
}
}
```

jse.createJson() will give the json as

```
{"A":10,"B":20,"C":30,"weekdays":["Sun","Mon","Tues"]}
```

and the d3js code which i m calling in .xhtml file is

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

<script>
var data;
d3.json("#{jsonBean.prepareChartDate()}",function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  data = json;
  console.log(data);
  //console.log("hello");

});

</script>
```

when i m printing in the console it is giving error in firebug.
[image: firbug screenshot]

Comment: Like the error states, there is a syntax error in your JSON.

{"A":10,"B":20,"C":30 should be {"A":"10","B":"20","C":"30"

Comment: @EmilKaminski : I changed the JSON tothis,`{"A":"10","B":"20","C":"30","weekdays":["Sun","Mon","Tues"]}`,but then also i m getting this exception,`missing ) after argument list
  d3.json("{"A":"10","B":"20","C":"30","weekdays":["Sun","Mon","Tues"]}",function(... ` in firebug,is there anything wrong with d3.json function or how i need to call the ajax request from d3 to jsf.

Comment: I am no expert in d3 but from what i can see in the documentation, is that the first parameter of the d3.json method is the url to the json file, and not the json output itself, like:

    d3.json("path/to/file.json", function(error, json) {...

Comment: @EmilKaminski  Thanks,i am actually having a problem with JSF syntax in xhtml,i am able to invoke the servlet from d3.json function but,`#{jsonBean.prepareChartDate()}` This is giving me error.Can we mix a servlet in JSF?if so,can u provide any link or suggestion.

Comment: Here is a link where someone is pasting json data into a highchart, perhaps it can be of help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414903/how-to-send-json-using-jsf2-primefaces-request-context-to-highchart

Comment: @EmilKaminski  Thanks i Shall i have look onto that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call a method in this way: ***#{jsonBean.prepareChartDate()}***.
You have to create a class like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class JsonBean implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public String getChartDate() {
    String jsonData;
    /* jsonData valorization */
    return jsonData;
  }
}
```

and call the method with ***#{jsonBean.chartDate}***

Comment: You don't call a GETTER this way. You  can call a method this,way, but it is not the right aay in this context. Please improve your answer